# Is there a library/ wrapper library that can do windows RDP method?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, remote-desktop, rdp

I had this situation I only have RDP access and the only way to transfer files over from local is copy and paste via RDP.

I would like to automated the process by writing a C# form application that can use the RDP protocol to do file transfer or other RDP stuff..

Is there a library available to do this?

Answer (score 0):

came across

[Where can I find documentation on the C# MSTSCLib, specifically the MsRdpClient classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000885/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-the-c-mstsclib-specifically-the-msrdpclient-c)

But still, i can't find any useful documentation for transferring file over via RDP (like how we copy and drop/delete off the remote server automatically)

Comment: It is the same MsRdpClient class that is used in the project in my answer, right?