# C# Remote desktop application using RDP. How to generate the certificate ?

Tags: c#, rdp

I have some problems to use the MSTSCLib to connect from 1 PC to another one.

It's working with Servers but not with normal Workstations...

```
    private void btn_connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            rdp_control.Server = tbx_servername.Text;
            rdp_control.Connect();
            tabPage1.Text = "Connected";
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void btn_disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdp_control.Connected.ToString() == "1")
        {
            rdp_control.Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Both client and server applications are in the Same Network under the same NAT. Problem is the certificate,... I need to find a way to include the certificate. With the normal Remote Desktop from Windows, you see a MessageBox with the question:"Do you want to use this certificate.... blablabla" But this is not coming up with the RDP function in c#

Any Ideas?
Thanks B.R.

Comment: What is the type of `rdp_control`? I'm assuming you looked at this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot, its "Microsoft Terminal Services Client Control - version 1"

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this isn't an issue in the code specifically but an issue with windows firewall and the way remote desktop is configured on the clients. Maybe take a look at the standard remote desktop client and see if you can connect before you work too hard on this code. Just a thought!

Comment: High, maybe i have to change something on firewalls, i will check.
But i can connect with the normal Remote Desktop :)

Comment: @drw_w 
Y i looked at this article already.
PS:
Firewall down, no changes

Answer (score 5):

Following code shows a simple RDP client and server.

**RDP Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDPCOMAPILib;
using AxMSTSCLib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace TCP_to_RDP_Converter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static RDPSession currentSession = null;
        public static void createSession()
        {
            currentSession = new RDPSession();
        }

        public static void Connect(RDPSession session)
        {
            session.OnAttendeeConnected += Incoming;
            session.Open();
        }

        public static void Disconnect(RDPSession session)
        {
            session.Close();
        }

        public static string getConnectionString(RDPSession session, String authString, 
            string group, string password, int clientLimit)
        {
            IRDPSRAPIInvitation invitation =
                session.Invitations.CreateInvitation
                (authString, group, password, clientLimit);
                        return invitation.ConnectionString;
        }

        private static void Incoming(object Guest)
        {
            IRDPSRAPIAttendee MyGuest = (IRDPSRAPIAttendee)Guest;
            MyGuest.ControlLevel = CTRL_LEVEL.CTRL_LEVEL_INTERACTIVE;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the form items
        /// </summary>
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            createSession();
            Connect(currentSession);
            textConnectionString.Text = getConnectionString(currentSession,
                "Test","Group","",5);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Disconnect(currentSession);
        }


    }
}
```

In order to use the RDP communication library you need to add rdpcompapi and Microsoft windows terminal services, form the COM references.

**RDP Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RDPCOMAPILib;
using AxRDPCOMAPILib;

namespace Simple_RDP_Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void Connect(string invitation, AxRDPViewer display, string userName, string password)
        {
            display.Connect(invitation, userName, password);
        }

        public static void disconnect(AxRDPViewer display)
       {
            display.Disconnect();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             try
            {
                 Connect(textConnectionString.Text, this.axRDPViewer, "", "");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to the Server");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can add reference to the AxRDPCOMAPILib by importing RDP viewer class component to the main form.

Full project can be downloaded from here [Download]:http://sandaruwmp.blogspot.com/2014/05/remote-desktop-application-with-rdp.html

Comment: Its in the Same Network.
Problem is the certificate,... 
I need to find a way to include the certificate.
With the normal Remote Desktop from Windows, you see a MessageBox with the question:"Do you want to use this certificate.... blablabla"
But this is not coming up with the RDP function in c#

Comment: Wait I will attach a simple RDP client server application that is using a connection string to connect. then you can follow that

Comment: Here certificate will be auto generated.. i used RDPCOMPLIB and AxRDPCOMAPILib instead MSTSCLib. according to my knowledge it is the latest.

Comment: is that means .... if 2 users connected on different networks are unable to use RDP on this code?

Answer (score 2):

use this....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MSTSCLib;

namespace RemoteTool
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MSTerminalServiceControl1.Server = textBox1.Text;
            MSTerminalServiceControl1.UserName = textBox2.Text;
            IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)MSTerminalServiceControl1.GetOcx();
            secured.ClearTextPassword = textBox3.Text;
            MSTerminalServiceControl1.Connect();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MSTerminalServiceControl1.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]