# C# connect WinForm App running locally via Remote Desktop (or other) to a Database

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, database-connection, rdp

**EDIT**

RDP is just the current way I do this, if there is another way to connect to a database in a different environment I will do that. Ideally I want this to connect to the database as it would if the executable was in the RDP environment and show no indication of connecting to the DB via the other environment.

**EDIT 2**

I have also tried adding a second connection string and opening it then having my current connection string immediately after, that didn't work.

---

I have a C# Win Forms application which connects to a database, this works fine except I need to RDP into the correct environment and have the executable ran from there to do so.

Is it possible to do the RDP connection inside of the application then connect to the database without having to have the executable inside the RDP.

I have tried to build up a connection string using the MSTSCLib library which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29519945/2641576) however this isn't working at code level anyway.

Code:

```
    private void rdpConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MSTerminalServiceControl1.Server = rdpServer.Text;
        MSTerminalServiceControl1.UserName = rdpUserName.Text;
        IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)MSTerminalServiceControl1.GetOcx();
        secured.ClearTextPassword = rdpPassword.Text;
        MSTerminalServiceControl1.Connect();
    }

    private void rdpDisconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MSTerminalServiceControl1.Disconnect();
    }
```

Current Path:

[image]

Desired Path:

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need the executable on the RDP server?

Comment: Because that this the environment the database is in, i want to have the executable locally and then "tunnel" though the RDP then to the DB.

Comment: Why not just connect to the database using the public IP address and lock the server down to a VPN? The RDP protocol isn't designed for what you want to use it for.

Comment: I have no access nor is it possible to change the set up

Comment: I would update your question with a higher level of detail on what you're trying to achieve and why. Its hard to help you if we don't know the circumstance.

Comment: My question is literally that, I want to have the RDP connection built into the app so i can have the executable locally

Comment: I have added terrible diagrams t show what I do currently vs what I want to do

Comment: The code for RDP looks fine, I have a similar code which is working. However, it might silently fail due to say some pop-up being thrown when you connect for eg. the Certificate Error popup that asks whether you want to connect anyway. So check the connection with Windows RDP App, if you get any message on connecting check the "Do not show this....." kind of checkbox and then try this code.

Comment: @ArifEqbal I get `MSTerminalServiceControl1 does not exist in this current context` & `The type or namespace name 'IMsTscNonScriptable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` & `The type or namespace name 'MSTSCLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You can connect to any database you can access. This is a networking issue. Your database just needs to be available from wherever you run your app. RDP is not a database connection protocol, so it makes no sense to try and turn it into one, what you want is an arrow from your EXE to the DB (not via RDP). It sounds like what you really need is a VPN

Comment: If there is a way to connect to a database on another environment without using RDP I will happily do it that way. RDP is just the way I currently do it non programmatically

Comment: Your error BTW shows that there is some reference problem, do you have the COM Control on your Form? Are you referencing "AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll"?

Comment: @ArifEqbal Im gunna go with no to both of them questions. Where can I add these?

Comment: The important word in that sentence is **non programmatically**. Your program is not a person interacting with the computer as you would. It sounds like you need to speak to your network administrator because this is simply a [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) issue. The important thing you really need to get you head around here, is even if you get RDP launched, **it will not help you connect to your database**. So I'd give up on this whole idea

Comment: @Liam I dont want to launch the RDP, thats just currently how i access that environment

Comment: @Matt Going back to connecting directly to the database - this is normally very possible. You set the port upon which the DB server listens for connections (normally 1433 from recollection). Then, add a firewall rule to permit incoming connections on that port. Then your connection string looks something like this `Data Source=ServerName,1433;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;`  Note the comma between the ServerName and the port 1433 Hope that helps.

Comment: I already have all of that information for the DB but it doesnt work unless the file is in the correct environment

Comment: Nobody suggested using an SSH tunnel, but that's what might help solving your problem. You'd need to install [SSH server](https://github.com/PowerShell/openssh-portable) where your DB is, then create a secured tunnel using (say) [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure, that can not work, because...

RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) is a Protocol to connect you from a remote machine to a session on a Terminal Server. That's the purpose. In that session, you can start programs, open documents and do your work. Like you were sitting in front of that machine. The benefit is, this can be done by multiple users, depending only on the number of user licenses and hardware power.

There a some special cases, e.g. you can start a program automatically on start up. Then your session is limited to this program and will end, when the program ends. But this is only a restricting. You will still start a session for that.

Also, there is a small version of Terminal Server build in every windows version, not only servers. This can be used a for a remote connection in the same way.

So, sad that, RDP can not connect to a database. In no way. You need a program for that. You can build a local program with a RDP-Client inside. That can connect to a session on a remote machine and start another program, that connects to the database. But you will have no communication between the to programs by default, so there is no benefit.

I think, like others said, the best is to connect to the database directly.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do not have references to the ActiveX Control.

In your Toolbox Choose the COM Component : Microsoft RDP Control - version x

The version here is important it should match the installed RDP version, once you have added this in your tool box drop it on your form, if there is  version mismatch it would throw error. I would say start from the latest version of control and go down till you are able to successfully add it to your form. The `MSTerminalServiceControl1` in your code is actually the name of this control that you should thus put on your form.

Comment: It should actually be installed in your system, the DLL is mstscax.dll and it should be located in Windows\System32, try referencing that through the browse option on COM Components tab.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to Connect multiple sql users to one database and no to use RDP.

you should write a special connection string, for each user something like below:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString =
    "Data Source=ServerName;" +
    "Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;" +
    "User id=" + UserName + ";"
    "Password=" + Password + ";";
 conn.Open();
```

Put this in a class that accepts the username and password.

Full example:

```
class myConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        string str = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User id=" +             
        UserName + ";Password=" + Password + ";";
        SQlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
        return con;
    }
}
```

Then connect each user to DB directly.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have app.config file for the executable, update the connection string parameter to point to the ip of rdp server.
Before you do this enable database port on firewall and also enable remote connections to database.
For mssql server.
Run sql server configuration manager.
Select database instance. 
Enable tcp/ip under network configuration.
Under io addresses tab.
Set tcp port to 1443.
Restart instance.

Data Source=IP,1443\dbservername;
I hop this can be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a Network Administrator configured our normal winform application to be opened remotely over `the Internet` using `Citrix`.
We made **no changes** to the exectuable file.
It will launch the application in the `Citrix Virtual Server`.

The problem is that it's a paid software.