# Remote Desktop Connection with c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, remote-desktop

How can i remote connection to the server through c#?

Comment: Have you seen, say, [C# Remote desktop application using RDP. How to generate the certificate ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545717/c-sharp-remote-desktop-application-using-rdp-how-to-generate-the-certificate)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Actually i don't want GUI with control. Is there another method?