# How to connect to a remote desktop in 'span' mode

Tags: c#, windows, mstsc

I am looking for some documentation or some code example to connect to a remote desktop using C# MSTSCLib and AxMSTSCLib while displaying the created window in 'span' mode when using multiple screens.
I would like to get the equivalent of the command:

> mstsc /span remote_ip

I only found this link [Where can I find documentation on the C# MSTSCLib, specifically the MsRdpClient classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000885/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-the-c-sharp-mstsclib-specifically-the-msrdpcl) but it did not help me much.
I am already able to connect to a remote desktop by calling

> connect()

on a

> AxMsRdpClient2

object. There are a lot of settings that can be modified to tune the behaviour or this object (authentication, etc) but I cannot find how to display the result in a window that fills multiple screens instead of only one screen.

Comment: This may not apply to you, but something keep in mind that only Windows 7 Ultimate allows for true multi-monitor RDP support. Professional wasn't enough for me to use my two monitors to RDP into my dual monitor work machine with proper dual monitor support.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted. The only trick is to set the following properties:

> _axMsRdpClient.DesktopWidth = ClientRectangle.Width;
>
> _axMsRdpClient.DesktopHeight = ClientRectangle.Height;
>
> _axMsRdpClient.AdvancedSettings3.SmartSizing = true;

before calling

> connect()

Once this method is called I do not think it is possible to change the size of the remote desktop.